# Can't set external monitor native resolution on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell U2719D 2560x1440 monitor and a Dell Inspiron 5593 with NVIDIA GeForce MX230 and Intel i5-1035G1. It is connected with a HDMI cable. The problem is, I can't set the monitor to its native resolution. The maximum I can get is 1920x1080.

I have updated all the relevant drivers (Nvidia and Intel graphics card and display), but still nothing. When I go to advanced display settings, it says, the display is connected to Intel grpahics card. Also, Nvidia control panel shows the display as connected to Intel. It doesn't show the display tab I have seen on some other answers. I tried playing with power mode settings, so the Nvidia is preffered all the time, but that doesn't change anything.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So, according to the [manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-5593-laptop_setup-guide_en-us.pdf), the MX230 doesn't support external display but the Intel one does. It has HDMI 1.4b which support 1440p60hz (although it's kinda old technology) so, do you have Intel control panel? Maybe there is some additional settings there.

Comment: The desired resolution doesn't show up. There is an option to add custom resolutions, but not working for me :/ I tried both higher and lower values.

Comment: Did you try using a different HDMI cable?

Comment: I just tried the monitor (and a cable) with a different laptop, and it sets the resolution correctly, so it has to be the problem with this Inspiron

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I have the same issue, there is no solution.
Dell is limiting the port to FHD so you won't be able to get anything higher than that.
https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-Inspiron-5593-Native-resolution-on-external-monitor-Dell/m-p/7419597/highlight/false#M68292
https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Dell-Inspiron-3493-Won-t-Output-4k-to-External-Monitor/td-p/7423761

Open a ticket with their support maybe they will understand that they need to do something about it.